# Как выполнить на jQuery то что выполняется по нажатию по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня на странице есть код HTML:

```
<div id="task-1" style="display: none">Сообщение отпрвлено!</div>
<a data-rokbox href="#" data-rokbox-element="#task-1">TEST</a>
```

По нажатии на ссылку открывается модальное окно с текстом "Сообщение отпрвлено!".
Не могу понять как сделать чтобы скрипт это выполнял автоматически без нажатия кнопки.

Answer (score 2):

> По нажатии на ссылку открывается модальное окно с текстом "Сообщение отпрвлено!". Не могу понять как сделать чтобы скрипт это выполнял автоматически без нажатия кнопки.

Повесить событие клика с желаемым результатом на элемент `a`, а потом вызвать это событие без участия пользователя.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Что должно быть при клике на <а>
  $('a').on('click', function () { 
     $('#task-1').css('display','block')
  })
  // Какие-то действия произошли до этого
  // ...
  // ....
  $('a').click() // Вызван триггер клика
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="task-1" style="display: none">Сообщение отпрвлено!</div>
<a data-rokbox href="#" data-rokbox-element="#task-1">TEST</a>
```

---

**UPD:**

Ссылка спрятана, но клик событие сработало.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Что должно быть при клике на <а>
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  В случае если это действие уже определенно, просто удалить
  $('a.after-submit').on('click', function() {
    $('#task-1').css('display', 'block')
  })
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // и вызвать $('a').click();
  // Какие-то действия произошли до этого
  // ...
  // ....
  $('a.after-submit').click() // Вызван триггер клика
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-------- Пример того что сработал триггер -------->
<div id="task-1" style="display: none">Сообщение отпрвлено!</div>
<!-------- Визуально удален, но нажатие отработало -------->
<a data-rokbox href="#" data-rokbox-element="#task-1" style="display:none" class="after-submit">TEST</a>
```

Comment: Мне не нужно чтобы показывало скрытый div , мне нужно, чтобы скрипт передавал такие-же параметры как и при нажатии на ссылку. Ссылку я указал для того чтобы из неё взять параметры, я её вообще хочу удалить, хочу чтобы это-же действие выполнял скрипт а не по нажатию на ссылку. <div id="task-1" style="display: none">Сообщение отпрвлено!</div> - это служит параметром для rokbox и уже rokbox его находит открывает в модальном окне содержимое этого div.

Comment: @Роман Какие именно параметры передаются при нажатии на ссылку? Куда передавал? Какой конечный результат? Как вы его видете? Возможно у вас есть код/фотка того как вы видете конечный результат? Ваш вопрос, об одном, а хотите вы совершенно другое.

Comment: https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-a5022205e1.gif

Comment: Это модуль джумлы RokBox:
http://demo.rockettheme.com/live/joomla-extensions/rokbox/
Настраивал ссылку по этой инструкции:
https://joomlaforum.ru/index.php/topic,76890.msg671515.html#msg671515
И частично с сайта rokbox, ну ссылку с горем пополам удалось настроить а вот как сделать чтобы вместо ссылки скрипт работал нехватает ума.
Вот как оно работает по ссылке:
https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-a5022205e1.gif

Comment: @Роман Можно визуально удалить ссылку (к примеру добавить в элемент `style='display:none'`), но вызывать её функциональность `$('a').click()`, для полного удаления нужно углубляться в работу плагина.

Comment: Зачем углубляться в работу плагина если по нажатию ссылки все работатет. Проблема в том, что в конце загружается скрипт, который после отправки формы должен кликнуть эту ссылку вместо меня или как-то передать данные которые происходят после нажатия на ссылку. В вашем примере все работает а у меня нет. Ну я в принципе уже смирился с тем что не получилось так как хочется. Но все равно вам спасибо.

Comment: @Роман надо добавить класс в элемент, `class="after-submit"`, в таг `a`. Тогда и у вас будет работать, вариант представленный здесь не имеет более одного тага `a`, у вас скорее всего присутствует больше, чем один.